# How can I get a word that I don't know but knowing the words after and before?

Tags: python, string

I have a string like

`" 89 o/t rep hi my name is hi my helo, 123, A, 89 o/d rep 129 / 314 judge asdfff"`

I want to get the `129 / 314` knowing that the word after it is always `"judge"` and the words before are `"89 o/d rep"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
before = '89 o/d rep'
after = 'judge'
b = s.find(before)
a = s.find(after)
print(s[b+len(before):a])
```

Answer (score 1):

With regex:

```
re.search("89 o/d rep (.*?) judge", s)[1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYyxDoMgGIR3nuLCBA3RoB10ME2fo@lgKhYaFfKDg09Pbe3Q8e6@78KWrF/qJlDObg6eEsgwFtGBo2nhy08RYB3mDUs/G7j4S9ZMXkFXtcJVHfDwhXXVokStz3itw9Ogj8M4jpwxMnGd0v5Npoimp4cV/M8TxekiD4crRHnTd8YCuSWJfSZx6FLm/AY)

Comment: how can i get the first "judge"? the word repeat after that and if i do it like that he get me the last one

Comment: @jordantreggia With a `?`, see the updated code.

Comment: that's perfect, one more thing, if one of the words needs to be a variable? let's say the first one. a = "89 o/d rep" how can i do that?

Comment: @jordantreggia `re.search(a + " (.*?) judge", s)[1]` or `re.search(re.escape(a) + " (.*?) judge", s)[1]`.